# postfix + Cyrus SASL - cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file

Tags: openbsd, postfix, imap

Everything is up and running and answer on calls but the login for postfix doesn't seem to work (it works for Courier IMAP, just not postfix).

Here's the error output:

```
Jun 30 22:22:10 HOST postfix/smtps/smtpd[31676]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[<my ip>]: TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Jun 30 22:22:10 HOST postfix/smtps/smtpd[31676]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
Jun 30 22:22:10 HOST postfix/smtps/smtpd[31676]: warning: SASL authentication failure: Password verification failed
Jun 30 22:22:10 HOST postfix/smtps/smtpd[31676]: warning: unknown[<my ip>]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: generic failure
```

Here's `/usr/local/lib/sasl2/smtpd.conf`:

```
pwcheck_method: saslauthd
mech_list: PLAIN LOGIN
authdaemond_path: /var/run/courier-auth/socket
log_level: 7
```

And the socket has been created:

`# ls -l /var/run/courier-auth/`

```
total 4
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel     5 Jun 30 22:19 pid
-rw-------  1 root  wheel     0 Jun 30 22:19 pid.lock
srwxrwxrwx  1 root  _postfix  0 Jun 30 22:19 socket
```

The `/etc/courier/authdaemonrc` says:

```
[...]
authmodulelist="authpwd"
[...]
authdaemonvar=/var/run/courier-auth
[...]
```

I have no clue why this is going wrong, or where to begin to check for errors since the log doesn't specify which file it's looking for or where the connection is going wrong.

## System:

- OpenBSD 5.3
- postfix-2.10.20130201-sasl2
- courier-authlib-0.64.0
- courier-imap-4.11.0

Note: increasing the log-level of postfix is of not use either, i'm doing the best i can to not annoy you with standard questions like this but i'm bashing my head hard at the moment!

Edit: I've also taken into account that postfix runs in a chrooted environment (tried not chrooting as well just for the sake of it) and thus i created /storage/spool/postfix/var/run/courier-auth/ and placed `socket` in that folder without any success. Also tried `symlinking` that chroot folder to the actual folder `/var/run/courier-auth/` also without success.

## Partial solution:

Ok so i've fixed SMTP, postfix can now use SASL2, however..
That ment dropping the support for Couerier IMAP... Eh..

Aparently there was some missing startup parameters in saslauthdaemond via `/etc/rc.d/saslauthd`, i had a missing `mux` file which worried me since almost every guide except the OpenBSD guide pointed to it.. so i fixed that by adding:

```
daemon_flags="-a getpwent -m /var/run/courier-auth/"
```

The startup script had no flags for whatever reason.. so that fixed some issues.
Now SMTP can authenticate, but now `imapd-ssl` says:

```
Jul  1 14:08:48 HOST imapd-ssl: LOGIN FAILED, method=PLAIN, ip=[::ffff:<ip v4>]
Jul  1 14:08:48 HOST imapd-ssl: authentication error: Connection refused
Jul  1 14:08:52 HOST imapd-ssl: authdaemon: s_connect() failed: Connection refused
Jul  1 14:08:52 HOST imapd-ssl: [Hint: perhaps authdaemond is not running?]
```

After actually starting up the daemon (....) i can now authenticate against SASL2 even with IMAP, however it just says wrong credentials..

## Further troubleshooting:

```
Jul  1 14:55:10 HOST imapd-ssl: LOGIN FAILED, method=PLAIN, ip=[::ffff:<ipv4>]
Jul  1 14:55:15 HOST imapd-ssl: LOGIN FAILED, user=MyUser, ip=[::ffff:<ipv4>]
```

The user is a local user and can login locally but even so the user shouldn't need a actual shell to login to the mail.

so i poked around and found out that `DEFDOMAIN="@domain.se"` is messing things up, so i removed that from `/etc/courier/imapd` and i got to the point where `SMTP` work and i get this from the `IMAP`:

```
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST authdaemond: Authenticated: sysusername=anton, sysuserid=<null>, sysgroupid=20001, homedir=/storage/vmail/anton, address=anton, fullname=Anton, maildir=<null>, quota=<null>, options=<null>
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST authdaemond: Authenticated: clearpasswd=MyPasswd, passwd=$1b$04$QQQ1c10x0AU3etWCJFrla.Rl22sevNhq24yXYxrq8IN7mEeGI20.
Jul  2 13:23:10 HOST imapd-ssl: anton: Account's mailbox directory is not owned by the correct uid or gid
```

But i'm not sure why because:

```
# ls -l /storage/vmail/
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail   22 Mar 13 01:06 .Xdefaults
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  773 Mar 13 01:06 .cshrc
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  398 Mar 13 01:06 .login
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  113 Mar 13 01:06 .mailrc
-rw-r--r--  1 vmail  vmail  218 Mar 13 01:06 .profile
drwx------  2 vmail  vmail  512 Jun 30 10:44 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x  3 anton  anton  512 Jun 30 10:44 anton
```